# Error message "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists"

Tags: java, jsp

I am currently working on my login and registration page using sublime text. When I try to register users for my registration page or try to login, the error message will pop up shown below. [image]

This is the format for my code shown below:

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="loginRegister" method="post">
        <table
            style="background-image: url('https://static.abbottnutrition.com/cms-prod/abbottfamily.com.sg/img/Article%201%20banner_tcm150-71042.jpg'); width: 500px;  height: 200px; margin-left: 20px; margin-left: 20px;">
            <tr>
                <td><h3 style="color: red;">${message}</h3>
                    <h3 style="color: green;">${SuccessMessage}</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3 style="color: Red;">Recipe Login Page</h3></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login"></td>
                <td><a href="register.jsp">Registration</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**register.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="loginRegister" method="post">
        <table
            style="background-image: url('https://static.abbottnutrition.com/cms-prod/abbottfamily.com.sg/img/Article%201%20banner_tcm150-71042.jpg'); width: 500px;  height: 200px; margin-left: 20px; margin-left: 20px;">
            <tr>
                <td><h3 style="color: Black;">Recipe Registration Page</h3></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3 style="color: red;">${message}</h3>
                    <h3 style="color: green;">${SuccessMessage}</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"></td>
                <td><a href="login.jsp">Login</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyRecipeProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**CustomerDAO.java**

```
public interface CustomerDAO {
    
    public int insertCustomer(Customer c);
    public Customer getCustomer(String email,String pwd);
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer {
    private String email;
    private String pwd;

    public String getemail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setemail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getpwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setpwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

}
```

**LoginRegister.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginRegister
 */
@WebServlet("/loginRegister")
public class LoginRegister extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginRegister() {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {   
        CustomerDAOImpl cd = new CustomerDAOImpl();
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
        String submitType = request.getParameter("submit");
        Customer c = cd.getCustomer(email, pwd);
        //if (submitType.equals("login") && c!=null && c.getName()!=null)
        
        if (submitType.equals("login") && c!=null && c.getName()!=null) {
            request.setAttribute("message", c.getemail());
            request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } else if (submitType.equals("register")) {
            c.setemail(request.getParameter("email"));
            c.setpwd(pwd);
            cd.insertCustomer(c);
            int t = 0;
            /*if(cd.insertCustomer(c) > t) {
                request.setAttribute("Successmessage", "Registration Done, please login to continue!!!!");
                
            }
            else {
                request.setAttribute("not successful", "try again");
            }
            */
            request.setAttribute("SuccessMessage", "Registration Done, please login to continue!!!!");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("message", "Data Not Found, click on Register !!!");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            System.out.println(c.getemail());
        }
    }

}
```

**CustomerDAOImpl.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    static Connection con;
    static PreparedStatement ps;

    public int insertCustomer(Customer c) {   //put from frontend data to database

        int status = 0;
        try {                                  
            con = MyConnectionProvider.getConnection();                           
            ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into accountInfo values(?,?)");  // putting data in sql
            ps.setString(1, c.getemail());                                // before putting into sql, must put user data from frontend to customer object in servlet
            ps.setString(2, c.getpwd());                                //and then call from here using customer object call and push to database
            status = ps.executeUpdate();    //if want to put data, always update
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return status;

    }

    public Customer getCustomer(String email, String pwd) {   //call data from database

        Customer c = new Customer();
        try {
            con = MyConnectionProvider.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from accountInfo where email=? and pwd=?");  //prepare statement   to just call all data containing username and password
            ps.setString(1, email);  //input
            ps.setString(2, pwd);       

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  //call from database
            while (rs.next()) {                         
                c.setemail(rs.getString(1));
                c.setpwd(rs.getString(2));            //get data from database then put into the customer object
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body style="color: yellow;">
<h1>Hi ${message} !!! We welcome you !!!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**MyProvider.java**

```
public interface MyProvider {
    
    String username="root";  //password of database
    String pwd="xxxx";
    String connUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userinfo?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"; //postgresql==.mysql
}
```

**MyConnectionProvider.java**

```
import java.sql.*;


public class MyConnectionProvider implements MyProvider {

    private static final String DRIVER_NAME = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    // private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdb";
    // local machine
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userinfo?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    // Establish connection

    /**
     * Establish connection
     * 
     * @return Connection object
     * @throws SQLException throws SQLException
     */
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        // return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "yJfcXQETOLH1");
        // local machine
        System.out.println(DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userinfo?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC").toString());

        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "xxxx");
    }

    // Close connection

    /**
     * Close connection
     * 
     * @param conn Connection object
     * @param stmt Statement object
     * @param rs   ResultSet object
     */
    public static void close(Connection conn, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, I create a folder called myWebProject, and I saved all my codings and pages under a sub-folder called DIPProject as shown below and I run using Tomcat[image][image][![][image][6][image]

I would appreciate if someone can help me on that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Comment: Please try using  <form action="/DIPProject/loginRegister" method="post">